# Como usar um template como tipo em uma map?

Tags: c++, map, c++17

Existe alguma forma de usar template como tipo em um map no C++17?

```
template<typename T>
std::map<std::string, T/* tipo desconhecido, pode ser qualquer tipo */> map_exemplo;
```

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo onde iria utilizar isto ? Regra geral os templates são utilizados em classes ou funções no qual este exemplo faria sentido e funcionaria na perfeição.

Comment: Se eu entendi, você quer saber se há como deixar o tipo de cada elemento no mapa ser qualquer um (i.e. heterogêneo)?

Comment: Eu consegui, mas eu preciso usar um for separado para cada tipo, existe alguma forma de acessar todos os elementos em um único for?

Isac um exemplo(Com o problema acima que descrevi): https://paste.ofcode.org/Rfd42R7EW2zqbP7z5A3vVy

É exatamente isso @MárioFeroldi

Comment: Parece-me que a sua duvida real não joga com a pergunta. O objetivo dos templates é permitir definir um tipo especifico a ser utilizado numa função ou classe, que se possa variar quando instancia um objeto ou chama a função. No caso e de acordo com o que escreveu na resposta existente o seu objetivo é ter valores de tipos diferentes no mesmo `map`.

Comment: @Isac, nitpick: template também aplica-se em variáveis top-level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) introduziu o tipo [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any), um contêiner capaz de guardar objetos de qualquer tipo*. Exemplos:

```
#include <any>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::any a = 42; // int
    a = 3.14f; // float
    a = true; // bool
    a = std::string("Hello, World!"); // std::string
}
```

Você pode resgatar o valor de um `std::any` para o seu tipo original com [`std::any_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast).

No seu problema, o tipo do valor de elemento do `map_exemplo` poderia ser definido como `std::any`, então toda vez que criar uma nova entrada no `map_exemplo`, o tipo do elemento não importará. Como nem tudo é um mar de rosas, entretanto, para iterar sobre os elementos desse contêiner, você terá de codificar os tipos que espera que os elementos tenham:

```
#include <map>
#include <any>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::any> map_exemplo;

    map_exemplo["a"] = 42;
    map_exemplo["b"] = 3.14f;
    map_exemplo["c"] = true;

    for (const auto &[chave, valor] : map_exemplo) {
        if (auto ptr = std::any_cast<int*>(&valor)) {
            // ...
        }
        else if // ...
    }
}
```

O propósito de `std::any` está mais voltado para substituir o uso do tipo `void *` para guardar dados do usuário. No seu caso, o tipo [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) serviria melhor para suas necessidades, pois com ele dá pra definir quais tipos são esperados, e o acesso aos objetos é feito com [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit):

```
#include <map>
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

// Classe ajudante para sobrecarregar lambdas.
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::variant<int, float, bool>> map_exemplo;

    map_exemplo["a"] = 42;
    map_exemplo["b"] = 3.14f;
    map_exemplo["c"] = true;

    for (const auto &[chave, valor] : map_exemplo) {
        std::visit(overloaded {
            [] (int i) { std::printf("int: %d\n", i); },
            [] (float f) { std::printf("float: %f\n", f); },
            [] (bool b) { std::printf("bool: %s\n", b ? "true" : "false"); }
        }, valor);
    }
}
```

---

* Algumas regras aplicam-se aqui para que um objeto possa ser guardado por um `std::any`, como, por exemplo, satisfazer o requirimento de ser construtivo.

Comment: Sensacional sua resposta, uma pequena dúvida, os tipos de uma variant podem ser selecionados em tempo de compilação?

Comment: @cYeR, se por "selecionado em tempo de compilação" você diz "definir quais tipos um dado variant aceita," então sim, isso é obrigatório. Agora, se você quis dizer se "é possível usar variant em expressões constantes," a resposta também é sim, os [construtores de std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant) são `constexpr`, exceto pelos ctor de cópia.